# Combining a Header and Gridlistlayout Blackberry qnx momentics IDE

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I am a complete noob with regards to Blackberry development. I would like to know if it is possible to group items by header. Example: If the header is "Test", and then display a couple of items in a grid beneath it, and then have another header "Testing" and display some more items, so on and so forth. Would something like this be possible? (What I have in mind would look like the contacts on a android device, but the contact names would not be displayed in a list, but rather in grid form) I would appreciate any advice as I am currently working through the sample apps available on the BB dev site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would certainly be possible. The GroupDataModel with the ListView have that functionality baked in. You may want to use the GridListLayout if your heart is set on a grid layout.